# Trouble reading a parquet file into jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, scala, jupyter-notebook, parquet, apache-zeppelin

I uploaded a parquet file into amazon s3 from zeppelin and I'd like to download it into jupyter notebooks with python.

Here's my upload code in scala

```
myFile.write.parquet("s3://company/myFile")
```

Here's my download code in python

```
import pandas
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

pandas_dataframe = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://company/myFile', filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()
pandas_dataframe.to_csv("myFile.csv")
```

It gives me back this error

> ArrowNotImplementedError: Reading lists of structs from Parquet files
>   not yet supported: key_value: list not null> not null

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/3371 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1644 with comment from 2017: `At the moment we do not have mixed-nesting reading and writing implemented. If the nesting levels are all repeated (lists) or all groups (structs) vs. a mix (structs and lists/repeated fields) then we can read and write them. .. we could really use some help with the encoding and decoding of nested data. I will eventually get to it if no one else does but that could be anytime from 1 month from now to 6 months from now given how many other projects I have before me`

Comment: I don't understand what part of this is nested because it usually works for other parquet files.

Comment: I figured it out - my file had maps in it and parquet importer can't handle them

Comment: This looks like something others may encounter.  I would suggest posting an answer to your own question describing the problem a little more and how you resolved it.